# mclapply() chokes when elements to be parallelized on are too big - how to get around this?

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I am trying to parallelize a big operation in R. I am using mclapply().
The parallelization is done on a relatively small number of operations (50) but each operation is costly, in the order of the tenth of second. Therefore, the naive overhead problem, applying parallelization on too few, too little tasks, is no trouble here. Also, the objects that are used for the computations are big, but since I am using fork parallelism there should not be any copy.

However, it turns that solving the problem in parallel is costlier than in sequence !
How comes ? Any idea get around it ?

Minimal working example :

```
M = Matrix::bdiag(lapply(seq(5000), function(i)matrix(rnorm(9),3)))
M_list = list();for(i in seq(500))M_list[[i]]=M
B = Matrix::sparseMatrix(i = seq(15000), j = ceiling(50*runif(15000)), x = rnorm(15000))

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  lapply(M_list, FUN = function(x, B) { x %*% B }, B = B),
  parallel::mclapply(mc.cores = 4, M_list, FUN = function(x, B) { x %*% B}, B = B)
  , times = 5
)
```

Edit : thanks to @HenrikB 's answer, it seems clear to me that there was overhead after all. I think that it is due to the size of the returned object. If you run the following, parallel is useful again.

```
M = Matrix::bdiag(lapply(seq(5000), function(i)matrix(rnorm(9),3)))
M_list = list();for(i in seq(500))M_list[[i]]=M
B = Matrix::sparseMatrix(i = seq(15000), j = ceiling(50*runif(15000)), x = rnorm(15000))

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  lapply(M_list, FUN = function(x, B) { x %*% B }, B = B),
  parallel::mclapply(mc.cores = 4, M_list, FUN = function(x, B) { Matrix::t(B) %*% x %*% B}, B = B)
  , times = 5
)
```

Comment: Hello @onyambu, thank you for answering. I think that there might be some misunderstandings here. Since I am using sparse matrices here, the cost of multiplication is not $O(n^3)$ (and since B has only 10 columns, the actual cost would be $O(n^2)$). Anyway, if I was not using sparse matrices, I do not think that those matrices would even fit into my RAM. However, you are right when you say that there might be other ways to program what I want to program, but they have their own disadvantages. Save this problem with parallelization, I think that my current approach is a sensible one.

Comment: @onyambu Is it ? Maybe there is a problem with my computer or with my R installation because in the MWE I provided it is not.

Comment: Why don't you run the MWE before commenting ? The point here is that mclapply takes one order of manitude more time than lapply, so there is no need for large sample size here.

Comment: Have you monitored the memory consumption while running this? It could be that the `x %*% B` calculation requires a lot of memory, and if you run four of those in parallel, you might end up using more RAM than you have available, which often leads to swapping memory to disk (depending on OS).  Try to see what happens when you try with `mc.cores = 3` and `mc.cores = 2`.  When you use `mc.cores = 1`, it'll fall back to a vanilla `lapply()` internally.

Comment: Not that it matters here, but it's good to know that, instead of relying on global variables (here `B`), it's better to pass them as explicit arguments. In this case, `lapply(M_list, FUN = function(x, B) { x %*% B }, B = B)`.  That avoids global variables and makes it more clear what goes into the call. It also translates better to other parallel frameworks that does not look for globals, e.g. `parallel::parLapply(X = M_list, fun = function(x, B) { x %*% B }, B = B, cl = cl)`. All in all, your code will be more robust this way.

Comment: Hello @HenrikB, thank you for your answers. I have monitored the memory consumption. There is no swapping, even though parallel consumes more RAM than sequential. It may have something to do with my problem. And thank you for your advice on explicit arguments !

Answer (score 3):

I had a look. It turns out, this one falls under the classical "The overhead from parallelization is greater than the performance gain".  We can see this if we profile the code using, for instance, **[proffer](https://cran.r-project.org/package=proffer)**;

```
library(Matrix)
library(parallel)

## Create a 15000-by-15000 sparse matrix (dgCMatrix; ~ 600 kB)
M <- bdiag(lapply(seq_len(5000L), FUN = function(i) matrix(rnorm(9L), nrow = 3L)))

M_list <- vector("list", length = 500L)
for (ii in seq_along(M_list)) M_list[[ii]] <- M

## Create a 15000-by-50 sparse matrix (dgCMatrix; ~ 180 kB)
n <- nrow(M)
B <- sparseMatrix(i = seq_len(n), j = ceiling(50*runif(n)), x = rnorm(n))

FUN <- function(x, B) { x %*% B }


## Profile lapply()
proffer::pprof(lapply(M_list, FUN = function(x, B) { x %*% B }, B = B, mc.cores = 4L))
# Flat  Flat%   Sum%    Cum Cum%    Name    Inlined?
# 15    83.33%  83.33%  17  94.44%  _Call   
# 1 5.56%   88.89%  1   5.56%   isVirtualExt    
# 1 5.56%   94.44%  1   5.56%   _classEnv   
# 1 5.56%   100.00% 18  100.00% %*% 
# 0 0.00%   100.00% 1   5.56%   vapply  
# 0 0.00%   100.00% 18  100.00% record_rprof    
# 0 0.00%   100.00% 18  100.00% record_pprof    
# 0 0.00%   100.00% 18  100.00% proffer::pprof  
# 0 0.00%   100.00% 18  100.00% lapply  
# 0 0.00%   100.00% 1   5.56%   _selectSuperClasses 
# 0 0.00%   100.00% 18  100.00% FUN

## Profile mclapply() with 4 parallel workers
proffer::pprof(mclapply(M_list, FUN = function(x, B) { x %*% B }, B = B, mc.cores = 4L))
# Flat  Flat%   Sum%    Cum Cum%    Name
# 12    54.55%  54.55%  12  54.55%  readChild   
# 9 40.91%  95.45%  9   40.91%  unserialize 
# 1 4.55%   100.00% 1   4.55%   mcfork  
# 0 0.00%   100.00% 22  100.00% record_rprof    
# 0 0.00%   100.00% 22  100.00% record_pprof    
# 0 0.00%   100.00% 22  100.00% proffer::pprof  
# 0 0.00%   100.00% 22  100.00% mclapply    
# 0 0.00%   100.00% 1   4.55%   lapply  
# 0 0.00%   100.00% 1   4.55%   FUN
```

Contrary to `lapply()` who spends most of its time processing `FUN`, `mclapply()`, comes with a lot of overhead from parallel orchestration (`readChild()`, `unserialize()`, and `mcfork()`).

In summary, the processing time in `FUN` is so short that it's not worth parallelizing.

Comment: Hey @HenrikB, I forgot to thank you - a long time ago -  for this answer. Better late than never, I guess.